# I have problem in google script for my google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to transfer two columns from each sheet (Safaa, Nada, and Ahmed) based on a checkbox on each sheet. If they press 'Qualified,' the two columns should move to the 'Qualified' sheet, and if they press 'Needs Qualification,' the two columns should move to the 'Needs Qualification' sheet. However, the results are very strange and repetitive, and I don't know why. I need help.

[this is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvR0r.png)

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you be able to provide sample sheet? [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script that will handle the checks and the unchecks using the Properties Service to store where the saves have been made so that they can be undone. It still needs a bit more debugging but it's a start.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const incl = ["Sheet0", "Sheet1", "Sheet2"];
  const idx = incl.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    let saves = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("saves"));
    if (!saves) { saves = {}; }
    let dsh;
    if (e.range.columnStart == 8) {
      dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
    } else if (e.range.columnStart == 9) {
      dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
    }
    let nr = dsh.getLastRow() + 1;
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 3, 1, 2).copyTo(dsh.getRange(nr, 1));
    let p = `${incl[idx]}`
    if (!saves.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      saves[p] = [{ sheet: p, row: e.range.rowStart, cbcol: e.range.columnStart, dsh: dsh.getName(), drow: nr }];
    } else {
      saves[p].push({ sheet: p, row: e.range.rowStart, cbcol: e.range.columnStart, dsh: dsh.getName(), drow: nr })
    }
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("saves", JSON.stringify(saves))
  }
  if (~idx && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate2")
    let saves = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("saves"));
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(saves));
    if (!saves) {
      e.source.toast(`saves property not found`);
      return;
    } else {
      let vs = saves[`${incl[idx]}`];
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
      vs.forEach((obj,i) => {
        if(obj.row == e.range.rowStart && obj.cbcol == e.range.columnStart ) {
          let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName(obj.dsh);
          dsh.getRange(obj.drow,1,1,dsh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
          saves[`${incl[idx]}`].splice(i,1);
          PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("saves",JSON.stringify(saves))
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This is just a little helper function that you can use to display the ScriptProperties.

```
function lookatSaves() {
  const saves = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("saves");
  const html = `<textarea cols="50" rows="12">${saves}</textarea>`;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(700).setHeight(600),"Saves Dialog");
}
```

I played with this a while and I found that you are wise to wait for the final toast to confirm a Save or a Clear.  This will give each action the time it requires to insure that the object array got properly saved script properties.  I've also included some simple tools that make reviewing the contents of the saves property.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry")
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const incl = ["Sheet0", "Sheet1", "Sheet2"];
  const idx = incl.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    let saves = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("saves"));
    if (!saves) { saves = {}; }
    let dsh;
    if (e.range.columnStart == 8) {
      dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet3");
    } else if (e.range.columnStart == 9) {
      dsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
    }
    let nr = dsh.getLastRow() + 1;
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 3, 1, 2).copyTo(dsh.getRange(nr, 1));
    let p = `${incl[idx]}`
    if (!saves.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      saves[p] = [{sheet: p, row: e.range.rowStart, cbcol: e.range.columnStart, dsh: dsh.getName(), drow: nr }];
    } else {
      saves[p].push({sheet: p, row: e.range.rowStart, cbcol: e.range.columnStart, dsh: dsh.getName(), drow: nr })
    }
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("saves", JSON.stringify(saves));
    let sobj = saves[p][saves[p].length - 1]
    e.source.toast(`SSheet: ${sobj.sheet} SRow: ${e.range.rowStart} has been saved in DSheet: ${sobj.dsh}} DRow: ${sobj.drow}`,"Saved", 10000);
  }
  if (~idx && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.value == "FALSE") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate2")
    let saves = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("saves"));
    //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(saves));
    if (!saves) {
      e.source.toast(`saves property not found`);
      return;
    } else {
      let vs = saves[`${incl[idx]}`];
      //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs));
      vs.forEach((obj,i) => {
        if(obj.row == e.range.rowStart && obj.cbcol == e.range.columnStart ) {
          let dsh = e.source.getSheetByName(obj.dsh);
          dsh.getRange(obj.drow,1,1,dsh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
          saves[`${incl[idx]}`].splice(i,1);
          PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("saves",JSON.stringify(saves));
          e.source.toast(`Sheet: ${obj.dsh} Row: ${obj.drow} has been cleared`,"Cleared",10000);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}

function lookatSaves() {
  const saves = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("saves");
  const html = `<style>input{padding:2px;}</style><input type="button" value="Delete Saves" onClick="google.script.run.deleteMySaves();"/><br><textarea cols="70" rows="12">${saves}</textarea><br><input type="button" value="Refresh Saves" onClick="google.script.run.lookatSaves()"/>`;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setWidth(750).setHeight(500),"Saves Dialog");
}

function deleteMySaves() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty("saves");
  lookatSaves();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

  if (
    (src.getName() === "Safa" || src.getName() === "Nada_2" || src.getName() === "Ahmad") &&
    r.rowStart > 3
  ) {
    const destQualified = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Qualified");
    const destPreparation = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Preparation Course");
    
    if (r.columnStart === 8) { // Column H (8) for 'Qualified' checkbox
      src.getRange(r.rowStart, 3, 1, 2).copyTo(destQualified.getRange(destQualified.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2));
    } else if (r.columnStart === 9) { // Column I (9) for 'Needs Qualification' checkbox
      src.getRange(r.rowStart, 3, 1, 2).copyTo(destPreparation.getRange(destPreparation.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 2));
    }
  }
}
```

1. The conditional statements in your script have syntax errors.
   Instead of (src.getName() !'= "Safa" it should be (src.getName() !=
   "Safa". Similarly, the other conditions have similar syntax errors.
2. There are some formatting issues and extraneous characters such as +
   and 3 that seem to be causing problems.
3. You seem to be copying the same range (r.rowStart, 3, 1, 2) to the
   destination sheet in both cases. I assume you want to copy different
   columns based on the checkboxes.

Comment: thank you
but when I change the value of the check box after I filled it , the value duplicate in two sheets (qualified and preperation)